# Auto set active subitem segment value in Stock Item screen

Tags: erp, acumatica

How can I set active all sub-item segments in Subitems tab Stock Items screen using code ? The INSubItemSegmentValue class does not contain the active field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution

```
PXCache cache = Base.Caches[typeof(INSubItemSegmentValueList.SValue)];

foreach (INSubItemSegmentValueList.SValue item in cache.Cached)
{
    item.Active = true;
    cache.Update(item);
}
```